# PDF to HTML and HTML to PDF solution in php

Tags: php, html, pdf, html-to-pdf, pdf-to-html

I need to convert a PDF document to HTML and after editing the html I then convert this HTML to PDF .
I use 'pdftohtml' ubuntu command (pdftohtml - program to convert pdf files into html, xml and png images) like PHP code below

```
<?php $output = shell_exec('pdftohtml create.pdf updated.html'); ?>
```

It convert the whole document successfully but it pass all image in top of the page.
Can anyone help me to do this job ?

Comment: have you considered the option inline_css = true ?

Comment: @AbdelrahmanWahdan .. thanks for your kind reply .. how can i make inline_css = true ? do i add it in shell_exec(); ??

Answer (score 0):

- You can preserve the layout of your document (headers, footers, paging, etc.) from the original `PDF` file in the converted `html` file using the “-layout” flag.

  ```
  $output = shell_exec('pdftohtml -layout create.pdf updated.html');
  ```
- If you want to only convert a range of pages in a `PDF` file, use the “-f” and “-l” (a lowercase “L”) flags to specify the first and last pages in the range you want to convert.

  ```
  $output = shell_exec('pdftohtml -f 5 -l 9 create.pdf updated.html');
  ```
- To convert a `PDF` file that’s protected and encrypted with an owner password, use the “-opw” flag (the first character in the flag is a lowercase letter “O”, not a zero).

  ```
  $output = shell_exec('pdftohtml -opw ‘password’ create.pdf updated.html');
  ```

[Source](http://www.howtogeek.com/228531/how-to-convert-a-pdf-file-to-editable-text-using-the-command-line-in-linux/)

Comment: i did all you mention ... your code works perfect but my concern is when i convert the PDF it move all images of PDF in the top of the html tag .... how can i prevent it ??

Comment: Which `PHP` library exactly did you use ? I have been using this one and it works perfectly : github.com/mgufrone/pdf-to-html

Comment: ok i apply your mentioned library ... it also convert it successfully but my problem is image .. image go to the top ... here my PDF screenshot : [pdf](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ncxcioipdg73rgd/pdf-image.gif?dl=0) ... and after convert HTML screenshot : [html](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cyx6cawukh4we6c/html-image.gif?dl=0)

Comment: Well, I expected to see a screenshot for `HTML` page not `PDF` file, because you mentioned that this problem occurs in the `HTML` page after conversion.

Comment: OK This is the HTML code screenshot  [HTML screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/u27zv05z4sp0za3/html-view.png?dl=0)